# how to go to changed url in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

i am a completely beginner in programming, and i am trying to make my first python script, and i have a url in this form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ID

where ID is changed every time in a loop, and a list of IDs given in a text file.

now i tried to do it this way:

```
if id_str != "":

     y = f'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{id}'

     browser.get(y)
```

but it opens only the first ID in the text file, so i need to know how to make it get a different ID from the text file every time.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Generally it can be something like this:

```py
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if id_str != "":
            y = f'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{id_str}'
            browser.get(y)
```

where `filename` is a text file containing questions ids.
Each line here containing a single id string.
It can be more complicated, according to your needs / implementation.

Comment: I believe the placeholder in the formatted string should be `id_str` and not `id`

Comment: it says:
 `name 'ids' is not defined`
ids.txt is the file name

Comment: Where do you see `ids` variable in my code?